# Replace left click behavior by ctrl-click behavior in a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I would like a DataGridView row selection to behave the same way than when holding the ctrl button down (Click a new row to add to selection, click again to deselect, etc.) But I want it using the left mouse button.

Can I set this behaviour or will I have to do it programmatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the DataGridView class does not support this type of behavior out of the box. In other words, you're going to have to do it yourself, which offhand does not seem all the difficult to do.

Comment: Indeed, I've looked around and it seems it has to be coded. Anyway I've dealt with it in another way : the client accepted the default behaviour :)

Comment: Getting the client to see things the right way is always the simplest and most elegant solution. :)